# How can somebody cash my state income tax refund check?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, check, income-tax-refund

I am not a USA resident but I've worked the last summer in the USA so now I want to get my state income tax back. I know that the money is coming in form of a check on my name. I need somebody else to cash it for me while still in USA without me being actually there. Is there any formal power of attorney/proxy document that I can make in my country to give it to my friend ?

Comment: Is the person depositing the check or getting cash?

Comment: Will you be getting the check first, or will your friend get the check before you see it?

Comment: Did you have or do you still have a US bank account?

Comment: The person is getting cash. I'm not going to see the check because I wont be in US. I never had a bank account there.

Comment: Couldn't you have the check sent to you in your home country?

Comment: Yes I could but in my country to cash a check it's a lot of paper work, time and money (as I have to make a substantial deposit in order to be able to cash it - money that I can withdraw after a long period of time even if I already cash the check).

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to use a bank account and have the refund deposited directly to it. But you said you never had a bank account, so that may be a problem.

Another option is to have the refund check mailed to you, and you deposit it in your local bank, converting to your home currency (or not, depending on local laws).

Generally, for another person to cash a check made out to you - you need to endorse it first. Physically, on the back of the check. That means you **have to** see the check.

Specifically with tax refund checks there's much more scrutiny since there's a lot of fraud going on with regards to tax refunds. Thus, I doubt a bank would allow a third party cash a check made out to you, without you actually being present there.

Comment: So there isn't any legal document that I can get for another person in order for them to be able to act in my name and cash this check ?

Comment: @ElenaIonescu you can execute a power of attorney - though would likely cost you more in lawyer fees than you'll likely get from the check.